# Invoke-Command error when I try to run a script on a remote computer

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I am trying to run a script which is located on my local computer on a remote computer and I have to problems:

first: it is trying to run the script on my local computer and I don't want it to do that

second: the script doesn't run on the remote computer

This is the command I run and the error message in question:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator> Invoke-Command -ComputerName UKBTH05TSV08 -FilePath "C:\TaskSchedulerEventViewerSetup.ps1"

The "ICSweep Script" source is already registered on the "localhost" computer.

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-EventLog], InvalidOperationException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewEventLogCommand



ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: The syst...file specified.:String) [], RemoteException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

And this is the content of the C:\TaskSchedulerEventViewerSetup.ps1 script:

> New-EventLog –LogName Application –Source “ICSweep Script” schtasks
>   /Create /XML "ICSweepscripttaskscheduler.xml" /TN ICSweepscript /RU
>   SYSTEM

Comment: Please edit your question, if you need to add to it. The comments are not the right place for this.

Comment: As I understand `Invoke-Command`, you are asking it to execute the script located on *your* computer on the remote computer. Either move the script to your computer or execute a scriptblok like `Invoke-Command -ComputerName UKBT -ScriptBlock {this get's executed on the remove computer }`

Comment: The script is already located on my local computer and in the right path. What I don't understand is why it is not running it on the remote computer and why it is running it on my local computer

Comment: You can execute the command on the remote computer without errors?

Comment: this file `ICSweepscripttaskscheduler.xml` should exist on the remote computer. also Please specify a path such as `c:\temp\xmlfile` so that schtasks dosent look in the windows folder for that file.   The evntlog source is probably also registered on the remote computer

Comment: Lieven, if I run the command on the remote computer it works perfectly fine. But I want to run it from another computer

Comment: I know you do, just trying to narrow down the possibilities. I would start procmon on the remote computer, execute from your computer and look at the procmon output for errors. (Tools -> Count Occurrences. Column: Result. -> Count). Check for access denied or file not found messages.

Comment: Kiran, Spot on. thanks for the solution. Once I changed it to C:\ICSweepscripttaskscheduler.xml it worked. I was completely blind. Thank you guys

Comment: thank you too Lieven, cheers guys

Comment: @Kiran, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this file `ICSweepscripttaskscheduler.xml` should exist on the remote computer.

also Please specify a path such as :

`c:\temp\xmlfile`

so that schtasks dosent look in the windows folder for that file. 
The evntlog source is probably also registered on the remote computer